# main.tex .....Missing \endcsname inserted , Extra \endcsname

Tags: errors, standalone

I tried creating a multi-file project as described in overleaf [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects#The_standalone_package), but I get this message

```
main.tex .....Missing \endcsname inserted
```

and this message

```
main.tex... Extra \endcsname
```

for the line where `import` is written.

Can someone help? I searched here and a little bit in the documentation of standalone package, but I don't understand what I did wrong. (notes: Some of the foldernames had a gap and somewhere else a middle bar is used for a file name. No pictures in the project. Just simple text. I use texstudio in ubuntu 18.04)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{\textit{ \textbf{TITLE}}}
\author{\Large\textit{AUTHOR}}

\usepackage{graphics}

\definecolor{dg}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{dr}{rgb}{1.0, 0.13, 0.32}
\definecolor{cerulean}{rgb}{0.0, 0.48, 0.65}
\definecolor{bv}{rgb}{0.8,0.0,0.0}
\usepackage[colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\section{Πρόλογος}
\import{HERE/I/PUT/THE/PATH/SOME-NAMES/HAD/A GAP}{INTRODUCTION}

\end{document}
```

Here is the first sub-file I have made too as a MWE if anyone needs it.

```
\documentclass[class=extbook, crop=false, 14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}
{\flushright\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{cerulean} }{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{-18pt}{-102pt}{10pt}


\usepackage{graphics}

\definecolor{dg}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{dr}{rgb}{1.0, 0.13, 0.32}
\definecolor{cerulean}{rgb}{0.0, 0.48, 0.65}
\definecolor{bv}{rgb}{0.8,0.0,0.0}
\usepackage[colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Θα ξεκινήσουμε.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would recommend  _not_ having file names with a space. But you can try enclosing the file name with double quotes -- that had worked fine for me in the past.

Comment: Check [CTAN import](https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf). I would advise to not use spaces on paths and files. Accordingly to package documentation (and my experience) add a "`/`" at the end of your path. `\import{folder/subfolder/}{fileNoSpaces}`.

Comment: I removed all the gaps and I also put a ```/''' in the end, but the problem remains.@FHZ

Comment: The names are in greek. I don't know if that is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be main part (in `main.tex` for example):

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \subimport*{subfolder/}{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

In this directory or in another but with path to it:

```
%subfolder/chapter1.tex
\section{Chapter 1}

\input{part1}
%\input{../partA}   % error, doesn't work like that
\subimport*{../}{partA}
```

And this one:

```
%/subfolder/part1.tex
\subsection{Part 1}
\lipsum[1]
```

And Also:

```
%partA.tex
\subsection{Part A} 
\lipsum[2]
\input{subfolder/part1}
```

Try to follow this example and it will work like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "main part" @WinnieNotThePooh

Comment: it is Your main tex document

Comment: Well Ι found after a long time another problem. The answer wasn't working, although the error stopped showing up,and I couldn't find why. the reason was that the file names were in greek. I changed the names in english and now it compiles perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @ΝικολέταΣεβαστού always welcome)